# Problem drawing some 16bit transparent images with PDPageContentStream.drawImage after updating PDFBox from Version 2.08 to 2.12/2.16

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've some very basic code which inserts an image into an existing PDF:

```
public class InsertImg
{
    public static void main (final String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load (new File ("original.pdf"));
        PDPage page = document.getPage (0);

        byte[] imgBytes = Files.readAllBytes (Paths.get ("signature.png"));
        PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray (document, imgBytes, "name_of_image");
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream (document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
        content.drawImage (pdImage, 50.0f, 350.0f, 100.0f, 25.0f);
        content.close (); 

        document.save (new File ("result.pdf"));
        document.close ();
    }
}
```

While this code worked fine in PdfBox 2.08 for all image files, it works under version 2.012 only for some images and does not work anymore for all image files.

(Background: We would like to insert an image of a signature into an existing and already generated letter. The signatures are all generated with the same software. In version 2.12 not all signatures can be inserted anymore. In version 2.08 all signature could be inserted).

The generated pdf-file "result.pdf" cannot be opened in Acrobat Reader. Acrobat Reader shows only the original pdf "original.pdf", but does not display the signature-image. It says "error in page. please contact the creator of the pdf".

However, most images can be inserted, so it is likely that the problem depends on the very image used.

The images are all ok, they are png's and where checked and verified with various imaging programs, e.g. gimp or irfanview.

Furthermore, the code above has always worked fine with PdfBox 2.08. After an update of PdfBox to version 2.12, the problem showed up and also the newest version 2.16 still produces the error. Still on the same image files, and still not on all.

NB: When I put the following line into comment, then no error shows up in Acrobat Reader, so the problem must be somewhere within drawImage.

```
    // content.drawImage (pdImage, 50.0f, 350.0f, 100.0f, 25.0f);
```

and the rest of the code seems to be fine.

Also, I've just tried starting with an empty PDF and not loading an already generated one.

```
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument ();
    PDPage page = new PDPage ();
    document.addPage (page);
    [...]
```

The problem here is still the same, so the issue does not depend on the underlying PDF.

Comment: You say yourself that *"it is likely that the problem depends on the very image used."* Thus, most likely example images are necessary to analyze the issue.

Comment: yes, sure. However, since the images are valid signatures I could provide the examples only on a personal way, e.g. by email.

Comment: please send to  tilman at snafu dot de. There has been a lot of optimizations in that part of the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug since 2.0.12 (wrong alternate colorspace for gray images created with the `LosslessFactory`) that has been fixed in [PDFBOX-4607](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4607) and will be in release 2.0.17. Display works for all viewers I have tested except Adobe Reader, despite that the alternate colorspace shouldn't be used when an ICC colorspace is available. Here's some code to fix PDFs (this assumes that images are only on top level of a page, i.e. images in other structures are not considered)

```
for (PDPage page : doc.getPages())
{
    PDResources resources = page.getResources();
    if (resources == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    for (COSName name : resources.getXObjectNames())
    {
        PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(name);
        if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject)
        {
            PDImageXObject img = (PDImageXObject) xObject;
            if (img.getColorSpace() instanceof PDICCBased)
            {
                PDICCBased icc = (PDICCBased) img.getColorSpace();
                if (icc.getNumberOfComponents() == 1 && PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE.equals(icc.getAlternateColorSpace()))
                {
                    List<PDColorSpace> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(PDDeviceGray.INSTANCE);
                    icc.setAlternateColorSpaces(list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```